# Circular reference I am not able to identify

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, config

This is the error message:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

This is the SecurityConfig.java file:

```
package com.example.demo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import com.example.demo.service.UserService;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService)
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/register")).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/admin/**")).hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

   
     


}
```

When I run the application with

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
```

which disallows the reference from being checked, I get another error:

```
Parameter 0 of method configureGlobal in com.example.demo.config.SecurityConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder' in your configuration.
```

Please guide me a bit, I am new to spring boot and self learning.

Comment: where are your FULL logs, and where is the code for `UserService`?

Answer (score 0):

you didn't need exclude SecurityAutoConfiguration,

Change @SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class }) to @SpringBootApplication

only you add static modifier to bCryptPasswordEncoder method

Change bCryptPasswordEncoder() to below

```
@Bean
public static BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
   return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: i am edited Answer